# Need dynamic checkbox value to change state of select box

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have a question that involves laravel and jQuery.

I have a form that has a multiple-select box that uses the [wenzhixin/multiple-select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/) jQuery plugin.

```
<script>
    $('#multiselect').multipleSelect({
      placeholder: "Select Landing Pages",
      filter: true
    });
</script>
```

The enabled/disabled state of that plugin is determined by the :checked/:unchecked attribute of a checkbox:

```
<script>
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#multiselect').multipleSelect("disable");
    } else {
      $('#multiselect').multipleSelect("enable");  
    }
  });
</script>
```

Ultimately what I need this to do is when the page/form is loaded, the select box needs to be enabled/disabled depending on the initial value of the checkbox:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="multiselect" name="landings[]" {{ ($post->global == "1") ? "disabled='disabled'" : '' }}>
          @foreach($landings as $landing)
            <option {{ in_array($landing->id, $post->landings()->select('post_landing.*')->lists('landing_id')->all()) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $landing->id }}">
              {{ $landing->title }}
            </option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
<label style="display: inline-block; font-size: .7em;">Global Post: </label>
          {!! Form::hidden('global', 0) !!}
          {!! Form::checkbox('global', 1, $post->global, ['id' => 'toggle']) !!}
```

That works. Now, lets say the value of $post->global is "1" (and the box is checked): If I want to uncheck it, then select some options in the select box, and then submit the form via POST, the values of the select box are not sent. Although, in my POST request, I can see that the $post->global value is sent correctly (global => "0")... but like I said, the request does not show the array of select values.

In the opposite case, everything works as expected: If the initial value of $post->global is "0" (and the box is NOT checked) I can set the checkbox to "checked" and submit the form, and the request of $post-global is "1". Likewise, I can also leave the box unchecked and select some values, and the request is sent with the array of values. I am confident the problem is here:

```
 <select multiple="multiple" id="multiselect" name="landings[]" {{ ($post->global == "1") ? "disabled='disabled'" : '' }}>
```

But if this doesnt work, how do I set the initial state of my select box to disabled/enabled based on the value of my checkbox?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o95nhfaw/1/

Comment: Instead of `disabled` make it `readonly`. `disabled` input will not submit data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just added a line of js to my if statement to remove the disabled attribute if the checkbox was changed from the initial value:

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#multiselect').multipleSelect("disable");
    } else {
      $('#multiselect').multipleSelect("enable");
      $('#multiselect').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
```

Thanks!